# How to prove conditional independence property holds if A and B are just independent

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I prove given independent variables $A$ and $B$, that 
given $P(A \cap B) \mid F)$ is equal to $P(A \mid F) \cdot P(B\mid F)$

Comment: "How do I prove..." With some trouble, one hopes, since this is not true.

Comment: A standard example (for random variables, translates easily to events; is a counterexample to many such claims): $X,Y$ are independent uniform random variables in $\{-1,1\}$, and $Z = XY$. Then $X,Y$ are independent indeed,  but really not conditionally independent given $Z$...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Pr(A) = \Pr(B) = 1/2$ and $A$ and $B$ are independent. Let the event $F$ be $\big[A \text{ or } B\big].$ Then $\Pr(A\mid F) = \Pr(B\mid F) = 2/3$ and $\Pr(A\cap B\mid F) = 1/3.$ And
$$
\frac 2 3 \times \frac 2 3 = \frac 4 9 \ne \frac 3 9 = \frac 1 3.
$$
So $A$ and $B$ are not conditionally independent given $F.$
$$
\begin{array}{r|cc}
& B & \text{not }B \\
\hline
A & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
\text{not } A & 1/4 & 1/4 
\end{array}
$$